# Comparing Topologies (Product and cofinite)

Tags: general-topology

I have a midterm coming up and would love some help/guidance (or solution) on this practice problem.

Let X be an infinite set with the finite complement topology. Let T1 denote the product topology on XxX and let T2 denote the finite complement topology on XxX. Prove that T1 is strictly finder than T2.

Thanks.

Comment: Think about what happens for the special case $X = \mathbb R.$ See if you can't write down and draw pictures of various basis elements for the two topologies. Then you should see it :)

Comment: For the product topology it would be rectangles, right? Then for the finite complement it would be a select few missing lines?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \in \tau_2$ and we want to show that $A\in \tau_1$: $A^c$ is finite, so by DeMorgan's Laws, we may assume (why?) that $A^c = \{(x_1,y_1)\}$ is a single point. Then consider
$$
U_1 = X\setminus \{x_1\}, U_2 = X\setminus \{x_2\}
$$
Then $U_1,U_2$ and $X$ are open in the finite complement topology on $X$. Note that
$$
A = (U_1\times U_2)\cup (U_1\times X)\cup (X\times U_2)
$$
Hence, $A \in \tau_1$.

As for strict containment, check that $U_1\times U_2 \in \tau_1\setminus \tau_2$.